# Doubt on the definition of closure of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, hamiltonicity

The closure of a graph $G$, denoted $cl(G)$ is defined to be  the supergraph of $G$  obtained  from $G$ by recursively joining pairs of nonadjecent vertices whose degree sum is atleast $n$ untill no such pair exists.[n=|V(G)|]

Here if we add edges to non agecent vertices with $d_G(u)+d(v)\ge n$, adding edge $uv$ means $d_{G+uv}(u)+d_{G+uv}(v)=d_G(u)+1+d_G(v)+1\ge n+2 > n$ still the degree sum is more than n. Can you please help me to understand the definition?

Comment: Can you please proofread and edit your question? (You can click on "edit" just beneath the question itself.) It contains some non-words (like "ning" and "verof") and some things that are clearly typos. It's also not at all clear what $n$ denotes in your definition of closure -- can you please explain?

Comment: A quick answer to your question is this: the definition surely should say to take a pair $u, v$ whose degree sum is "at most $n$", or the induction never terminates, for the very reason you observe.

Comment: sorry sir, I have edited my question.

Comment: you mean definition wrong?

Comment: The definition is right. (See J.A. Bondy, V. Chvátal, A method in graph theory, Discrete Math., 15 (1976), pp. 111-135.)  Note that the procedure only adds edges between nonadjacent vertices.  On a finite graph it must terminate.

Comment: where will it terminate? at complete graph? Consider the graph, $V(G)=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ $E(G)=\{ab,bc,cd,de,ef,fa,bf,ce\}$. I am getting $cl(G)=K_6$.

Comment: It doesn't have to terminate with a complete graph, but it well may.  If the result is $K_n$, it follows from a theorem in *O. Ore, Note on Hamilton Circuits, Am. Math. Monthly, 67 (1960) 55* that the original graph is Hamiltonian.  In fact if the result is Hamiltonian, so is the original graph.

Comment: Yes, I got a graph whose degree sum is <n for any pair on non adjecent vertices.here, I guess $cl(G)=G$. right?

Comment: Thanks, @FabioSomenzi; I missed the critical word "nonadjacent". Without that, the definition really doesn't make much sense (unless you allow infinite degrees, and infinitely many edges between the same pair of vertices...)

Comment: @Mathgeek Yes, in that case no edge is added and the procedures immediately returns $G$.